# Complex function, analyticity domain

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, complex-numbers

Find the function domain of analyticity

i)$f(z)=\frac{z^2}{z-3}$

ii)$f(z)=ze^{-z}$

To check the domain of analyticity of a function, I only need to replace $z=x+iy$ and check the conditions of Cauchy-Riemann?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, checking the Cauchy-Riemann equations should work. It <strike>doesn't seem like too much work either</strike> (it might be a little).

Both (i) and (ii) are products/quotients of analytic functions -- since $z^2, z-3, e^{z}$, and $z$ can be relatively easily checked to be analytic on the entire complex plane. Products of analytic functions on some domain are always analytic on that same domain, however quotients, e.g., functions of the form $f/g$, for $f,g$ analytic on some domain, lose analyticity (is that the right word?) when $g=0$. These problems essentially boil down to finding where (i) and (ii) are undefined.

Comment: But the conditions of Cauchy Riemann are sufficient to prove that the function is analytic in a certain domain?

Comment: Yes. They should be. It might be a little work, because I believe you'll have to separate each function you're given into their real and imaginary parts, i.e., into the form $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ for $u:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ and $v:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$. But if you take partials and set
$$
u_x=v_y,\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;v_x=-u_y,
$$
you'll get a system of equations. The solution set of that system should give you the $x$ and $y$'s such that $f(x+iy)$ is analytic. If you're not supposed to know what I said previously, do it this way and check your work by above. They should be the same.

Comment: I just thought a little about my previous comment and (I'm treating _analytic_ as equivalent to _holomorphic_, which is the term we used here) I feel I should add something. In general, complex functions can only be analytic on an _open_ set, so the solution set that you get must be open as well. Most of the time you can't just take a function that has no hope of being analytic, force these equations on it, and say that it is analytic at a point or something. That doesn't coincide with the definition.